# Remove decimals from numbers

Tags: crystal-reports

My formula spits out numbers formatted like `19.47` or `1.02`. How do I remove those two decimal places? I only want the integer value to display.

Comment: I found [this post](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=9104) after a quick search.   `totext({tablename.numericfield},0,"")`

Comment: This is important: Do you want to round the numbers? Or just have the decimals fall off? That could be the difference between a 19 and a 20.

Comment: right click on your formula field and format this number due to your desire.